# Automatically refresh internet pages in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, windows, web

We have many URL like :

> http://IP/info.php?gid_inv=1
>   http://IP/info.php?gid_inv=2
>   http://IP/info.php?gid_inv=3
>   http://IP/info.php?gid_inv=4

Is it possible to refresh each of these URL, with a loop, in a PHP script ?

We first tried to use an AJAX function to make it work. That was good but the AJAX part of the script is not interpreted when we run it with the cmd Windows command line (since we work with Windows OS). That is a problem because the execution takes a lot of time and we would like to run it automatically, at night.

Then we tried the file_get_contents PHP method but even if we get the content the pages are not executed and refreshed. Here is a snippet :

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://IP/info.php?gid_inv='. $i); 
    $myfile = fopen ('log.txt', w); file_put_contents('log.txt', $homepage); 
    }
```

Then we tried the header method with

> header ("Location : URL.php")

Same result..

And we are getting stuck..
Would you have any solutions to refresh internet pages with a PHP script (knowing that this PHP script has to be executed in cmd ) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to run this script from the PHP CLI (command line)

Comment: Why don't you use cron jobs for that?

Comment: I confirm I'd like to run the script from the PHP CLI

Comment: @Echoes Windows !== CRON But there is the Task Scheduler, but again javascript wont get executed from a CLI script

Comment: Then have you looked at using CURL?

Comment: The task scheduler does not run the ajax part of the script. Otherwise it would be great.. No we didn't looked at using CURL.. would you have any examples please ?

Comment: _Small Note:_ AJAX i.e. Javascript will not be run from a  PHP CLI script regardless of the OS you are using

Comment: Yes, [here you go](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) The manual is always the best place to start any venture into a new concept [and here too](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)